# Groups and morphisms making a lattice structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(1) Let X and Y be groups. Write mono:X->Y and epi:X->Y (resp.) to denote the existence of a monomorphism or epimorphism from X to Y (resp).

mono:X->Y would mean that there is a subgroup of Y isomorphic to X. A group G together the relation <= on its subsets X,Y etc. saying X <= Y iff mono: X->Y is a lattice: the lattice of subgroups.

Does the group together with the relation => on its subsets X,Y etc. saying X=>Y iff epi:X->Y form a lattice as well?

(2) I've learned about categories recently. For example, in some categories bijective morphisms are isomorphisms, and so forth.

Is there a word for when the morphisms in a category endow each object/structure (e.g. group, field, whatever) with a lattice structure? By this I would mean for a structure G, for any two substructures of the structure X and Y, we say X>=Y if there is an epi:X->Y, and X<=Y if there is a mono:X->Y? This then would give the structure (group, field etc.) two lattice structures on its substructures: One for monos, one for epis.

Or any well known property that guarantees this?

Comment: You ask for a lattice structure on each object, but you then seem to describe a lattice structure on the category instead.

Comment: Ah property (2) is what I really mean. Perhaps I should change or get rid of (1)

Comment: Now your first part has a lot more assumptions than this just being a category (talking about subsets of the objects for example).

Comment: Hmm OK, then I suppose what these assumptions are is a kind of augmenting question/issue. I don't know how to write down such assumptions.

Comment: I mean, topological spaces have subspaces etc., sets have subsets, monoids have submonoids. I don't think that I need non-substructure subsets actually.

Comment: Well, a subobject is something slightly different in a category in general (or at least it need not behave like you expect).

Comment: OK thanks. I have edited the question, perhaps it makes more sense now?